# How to use Retrofit2 + GSON -> Class with custom object?

Tags: android, gson, retrofit2, custom-object, nest-nested-object

I'm reading some of the another post inside stackoverflow, but I can't get it to work.

I have a data returned by the server, that has the next form:

**SERVER RESPONSE**

```
{
  "userData": {
    "username": "victor.javier",
    "email": "victor.javier@stackoverflow.com",
    "createdAt": "2016-05-11T09:55:14.720Z",
    "updatedAt": "2016-05-11T09:55:14.720Z",
    "id": "5733018274ddfad25"
  },
  "token": "SkpaNuXdzfrhiH06qGK93EH2ujM37hfk02F8o2EodYJumG"
}
```

My code POJOs are the next:

**User.class**

```
public class User {

    @SerializedName("userData")
    @Expose
    private UserData userData;

    @SerializedName("token")
    @Expose
    private String token;

    ... CONSTRUCTOR AND GETTERS/SETTERS

}
```

**UserData.class**

```
public class UserData {

    @SerializedName("username")
    @Expose
    private String username;

    @SerializedName("email")
    @Expose
    private String email;

    @SerializedName("createdAt")
    @Expose
    private String createdAt;

    @SerializedName("updatedAt")
    @Expose
    private String updatedAt;

    @SerializedName("id")
    @Expose
    private String id;

    ... CONSTRUCTOR AND GETTERS/SETTERS

}
```

I had copied from another post the next class to deserialize a GSON. The code is:

**RestDeserializer.class**

```
public class RestDeserializer<T> implements JsonDeserializer<T> {

    private Class<T> mClass;
    private String mKey;

    public RestDeserializer(Class<T> targetClass, String key) {
        mClass = targetClass;
        mKey = key;
    }

    @Override
    public T deserialize(JsonElement je, Type type, JsonDeserializationContext jdc)
            throws JsonParseException {
        JsonElement content = je.getAsJsonObject().get(mKey);
        return new Gson().fromJson(content, mClass);

    }
}
```

The retrofit implementation is:

**RetroFitImpl**

```
public class UserApiImpl implements UserApi {

    @Inject
    public UserApiImpl() { }

    @Override
    public User loginUser(String identifier, String password) {
        Retrofit retrofitBuilder = getRetrofitBuilder();
        UserRetrofitApi userRetrofitApi = retrofitBuilder.create(UserRetrofitApi.class);

        LoginRequestEntity loginRequestEntity = new LoginRequestEntity();
        loginRequestEntity.setIdentifier(identifier);
        loginRequestEntity.setPassword(password);

        Call<User> call = userRetrofitApi.loginUser(loginRequestEntity);
        Response<User> response = null;
        try {
            response = call.execute();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        User body = null;
        if (response != null) {
            body = response.body();
        }
        return body;
    }

    private Retrofit getRetrofitBuilder() {
        HttpLoggingInterceptor interceptor = new HttpLoggingInterceptor();
        interceptor.setLevel(HttpLoggingInterceptor.Level.BODY);
        OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient.Builder().addInterceptor(interceptor).build();

        return new Retrofit.Builder()
                .baseUrl(BuildConfig.API_URL)
                .client(client)
                .addConverterFactory(buildGsonConverter())
                .build();
    }

    private static GsonConverterFactory buildGsonConverter() {
        GsonBuilder gsonBuilder = new GsonBuilder();

        Gson gson = new GsonBuilder()
                .registerTypeAdapter(User.class, new RestDeserializer<>(User.class, "userData"))
                .create();

        return GsonConverterFactory.create(gson);
    }
}
```

I'm doing something wrong with the *buildGsonConverter* method because I'm getting a call to onError of retrofit everytime, so I think that it's a problem in the construction of the GSON.

Anyone could tell me how to parsing this to construct a GSON like the response of the server?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Check the example from retrofit documentation

http://square.github.io/retrofit/

You don't need to create own gson factory

```
.addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
```

And also add to build.gradle

```
com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson
```

Comment: I've removed the line, but it's not the solution. :(. Thanks Paul

Comment: You don't have to remove your line, you need to use gson convertor factory as in the exemple!

Answer (score 0):

You need not to create a pojo by yourself. You can use http://jsonschema2pojo.com to create a pojo US ng yur server response.

Comment: My pojos seems to be Ok, Prasheel.